# Flutter Async Await With FutureBuilder

Tags: flutter, asynchronous, async-await

I have a flutter screen which loads the screen below. The first time i run the code... it shows a blank screen. When i go back and click the link again, it works ok. I am not sure where the problem is. Is it the Async await or the Future builder?

The first time i run the code the print statement
print('inside the builder1'); runs but the second print statement
print('inside the builder'); which is inside the future builder does NOT.
when i go back and come back to the screen it seems to work just fine.

The app needs to be on a stateless widget and does not use any providers or state management at all.

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart';

List<BlogPosts> blogPosts = [];

class BlogPosts {
  int id;
  String title;
  String excerpt;
  String link;
  String imageUrl;

  BlogPosts({this.id, this.title, this.excerpt, this.imageUrl, this.link});
}

Future getImage(imgUrl) async {
  var url = Uri.parse(imgUrl);
  var imgresponse = await get(url);
  return jsonDecode(imgresponse.body);
}

getData() async {
  var url = Uri.parse(
      'https://www.amrafarms.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?_fields=author,id,excerpt,title,link,_links.wp:featuredmedia&per_page=1');

  Response data = await get(url);
  var postdata = jsonDecode(data.body);

  postdata.forEach(
    (data) async {
      //print(data.toString());
      int id = data['id'];
      var excerpt = data['excerpt'].toString();
      var title = data['title']['rendered'];
      var imgurl = data['_links']['wp:featuredmedia'][0]['href'];
      var link = data['link'];
      String imageUrl;

      var imgurl1 = await getImage(imgurl);
      try {
        imageUrl = imgurl1['media_details']['sizes']['thumbnail']['source_url'];
      } catch (e) {
        print(e);
        imageUrl =
            'https://www.amrafarms.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/gardening-150x150.jpg';
      }
      BlogPosts post = BlogPosts(
          excerpt: excerpt,
          id: id,
          imageUrl: imageUrl,
          link: link,
          title: title);
      blogPosts.add(post);
    },
  );
  print('data Built');
  return blogPosts;
}




import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../components/drawerWidget.dart';
import '../data/blog.dart';

class BlogScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Blog')),
      drawer: DrawerWidget(),
      body: Container(
        child: FutureBuilder(
          future: getData(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            print('building');
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
              print('done');
              // If we got an error
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                print('Load complete');
                final data = snapshot.data;
                print('inside the builder1');
                return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: data.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    print('inside the builder');
                    return Card(
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Expanded(
                              flex: 3,
                              child: Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                child: Text(
                                  data[index].title,
                                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                                ),
                              )),
                          Expanded(child: Image.network(data[index].imageUrl)),
                        ],
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                );
              } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                print('error');
                return Center(
                  child: Text(
                    '${snapshot.error} occured',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                  ),
                );

                // if we got our data
              }
            }
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(backgroundColor: Colors.green),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi! Did you try not use Expanded? For me looks like is it when I look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is your `forEach` loop. Currently, the empty list `blogPosts` is returned since using `async` only allows you to use `await` in the callback, but `forEach` does not await `(data) async {...}`. That's the reason why your inner print statement is not printed initially.

Change your existing loop:

```
postdata.forEach((data) async {
  // remaining code
});
```

to:

```
for(var data in postdata) {
  // remaining code
}
```